# Using Python to Go Through Every possible commbination in a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, cryptography

I am new to python and is just learning the basics. I am wanting to create a program that assists in cryptography. I got most of the ideas down in python like ceaser brute force, but I am stumped when it comes to this part. I want my program, that is given a string. Let's say ABC...

```
MyString = ABC
```

It should then bruteforce the string by going through every possible combination. 
Example: abc, abd, abe, etc. It should return those values.

Now I have seen this done in many cases but none like this...
I want the program instead of returning: aaa, aab, aac, etc. It should not give the same value to the same letters in MyString. In addition, it should not return diffrent values if the same in MyString. So if I have ssb then is should not return dfk because s and s should return the same value. Vice-Versa, if I have dks then it should not return aii because k and s are different.

Thank You

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, itertools/permutations is your friend:

```
import itertools
MyString = 'ABC'
for comb in itertools.permutations(MyString):
    print(''.join(comb))
```

output:

```
ABC
ACB
BAC
BCA
CAB
CBA
```